# Javascript : Comparing Arrays values to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

In my program I have to compare array values to a variable, but it looks like my array is only comparing the last value to the variable. How should I proceed to compare all of them?

Here is the code:

```
for(var n=0; n<arrayLength; n++) {
    console.log(occupiedArray[n][0]);
    if(occupiedArray[n][0] == clickedX  && occupiedArray[n][1] == clickedY ) {
        occupied = true;
    } else {
        occupied = false;
    }
}
```

And here is my array :

```
var occupiedArray = [[4,0],
                     [5,0],
                     [6,0]];
```

When I use console.log it displays 4,5,6 just like I wanted, but it's only comparing the '6' value to my variable 'clickedX'. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please post all your code, especially the code that makes you believe that only 6 is compared to your clickedX.

Comment: What is "occupied" supposed to represent at the end of the for loop? Whether any points collide?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of occupied each iteration so only the most recent comparison is reflected at the end of the loop. Instead, try this:

```
for(var n=0; n<arrayLength; n++) {
    console.log(occupiedArray[n][0]);
    if(occupiedArray[n][0] == clickedX  && occupiedArray[n][1] == clickedY ) {
        occupied = true;
    }
}
```

Here occupied can be set to true but once true can never return to false.

Answer (score 0):

maybe..

```
occupied = false;
for(var n=0; n<arrayLength; n++) {
    if((occupiedArray[n][0] == clickedX)  && (occupiedArray[n][1] == clickedY) ) {
        occupied = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

if occupied found, exit loop